# Associate a build artifact in yaml release pipeline

Tags: azure

In Azure Devops, I have two individual yaml pipelines one for build and another for release. I would want to link the build artifact in the yaml release pipeline ,like the one we have for classic pipelines. Is there anyway we can achieve the same for yaml release pipelines.

198982-release.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. If you want to be able to access your artifact across different stages in your pipeline, you can use output variables to pass it to the next stage in your YAML. Please follow the below script.

```yaml
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    condition: in(stageDependencies.A.A1.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Job B1
  - job: B2
    condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['printvar.shouldrun'], 'true')
    steps:
     - script: echo hello from Job B2
```

Comment: The link you had didn’t actually include a URL, so I removed it. Can you [edit] your answer to reintroduce the link along with an actual URL so that it’s hyperlinked?